# unique action for multiple excel files with vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, directory, unique

I'm trying to make a simple action (for example replace "," by ".") to several excel files into one folder at the same time. A same kind of problems has already been solved here. But the solution doesn't work in my case:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim FolderPath As String, FileName As String
FolderPath = "C:\my_folder\"

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
   While (file <> "")
       Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

       Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

       Workbooks(FileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
       file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

The macro works for my current file opened but not for the other present in my folder. Do you have any idea of how I could fix that?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not opening new files. You just loop through folder but all Cell.Replace statements are executed on your current worksheet. Use this in your loop:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= ...
```